# Проблема с выводом перед System.exit

Tags: java, консоль

```
if (yboi > yleftwerh) {
    out.println("NW");
    System.exit(1);
```

Не отображает в консоле NW. Как это исправить?

Comment: Покажите весь код программы.

Comment: Может быть `System.out.println("NW")`?

Answer (score 3):

Используйте следующий конструктор PrintWriter(System.out, true)

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (System.out, true);
        out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Comment: подскажите плиз, что означает true во втором аргументе конструктора?

Comment: @user31238, это означает autoflush. То есть не нужно руками вызывать `flush()` после каждого вызова `print/println` (смотрите мой ответ, там я явно выхываю `flush`, при втором параметре `true` этого делать не нужно)

Comment: Спасибо, прийму к сведению

Answer (score 2):

Судя по тому что у вас написано `out.println("NW")` вы используете свой `PrintWriter`. Чтобы вы увидели содержимое, нужно сбросить буфер, вызвав `flush()`.

То есть сделать так:

```
out.println("NW");
out.flush();
System.exit(1);
```

При использовании `PrintWriter` в маленьких учебных проектах удобно обернуть два вызова в один метод:

```
private static PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);

//...some code...

private static void println(Object o){
    out.println(o);
    out.flush();
}
```

и вызывать его когда нужно:

```
println("NW");
System.exit(1);
```

Comment: Можно обобщенный метод запилить, то же самое будет